# Como obter o número de dias entre duas datas em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, data

Boa noite! O banco de dados na qual trabalho me retorna duas datas em milissegundos. Como posso calcular a diferença em dias entre as duas datas?

**Exemplo:**

*Data1:* 1619226924035ms 
*Data2:* 1619406000000ms

*Retorno:* 5 dias

Comment: E pelos cálculos nos códigos das respostas, está retornando 2 dias e não 5.

Comment: @CmteCardeal sim sim... foi apenas um exemplo